# Make Text Editable/ReadOnly Based on Input using Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to achieve something where in a given input I make the string editable or non editable(readonly) based on the context of the text in vue js.

For example : 
I have a text: My Name is $John Doe$
Now my vue js code should iterate the string and the text between $ can be editable.

```
HTML:
<template>
     <textarea cols="10" rows="10" disabled>{{q | makeTextEditableByCondition}}</textarea>
<input type="text" v-model="editText">
</template>
<script>
    export default {
       data() {
        q : "My name is $John Doe$ from NYC,
        editText: null,
        disabled: true
     }
filters:{
  makeTextEditableByCondition(text){
      let splittedText = text.split("$");
      let this.editText = splittedText[1]
      splittedText.splice(1,1)
      return splittedText.join(" ")
    }
</script>
```

But It's still making the process complicated and I am not achieveing proper output.

Any help will be hightly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many things are not going well :

```
q : "My name is $John Doe$ from NYC",
```

Not ending tag for your filters "}"

> ... Filters should be pure functions and
>   should not be dependent on this context. If you need this you should
>   use a computed property or just a method e.g. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5998

Here a basic solution with computed :

```
<div id="app">
   <textarea cols="10" rows="10" disabled>{{ qComputed }}</textarea>
   <input type="text" v-model="editText">
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    q: "My name is $John Doe$ from NYC",
    editText: null,
    disabled: true
  },
  computed: {
    qComputed(){
      let splittedText  = this.q.split('$')
      splittedText[1] = this.editText
      return splittedText.join` `
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jupg4ysz/